# Get last non empty cell of a column from different Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

It is working fine if the filter is from local data or on that specific Google Sheet. But if I import other Google Sheet using ImportRange, I got this error:

> FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. column
>   count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 563.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
=index(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Data!51:51") ,max(filter(column(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Data!51:51"))), len(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Data!51:51")))))
```

This is working :

```
=index(53:53,max(filter(column(53:53),len(53:53))))
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I've tried but still got the same error. :(

Comment: thanks! I posted the working formula below. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using the following:

```
=INDEX(FILTER (IMPORTRANGE("URL", "RANGE"), NOT(ISBLANK(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "RANGE")))), COUNTA(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "RANGE")))
```

Thank you for the tip, [|'-'|](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/i-i)!